# Regex Matching Wrong Data

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, logging

So here is my link:

http://regex101.com/r/sL4eR0/5

For some reason, it is not matching the data I have inputted correctly. I am assuming it is because of the first matching group since it matches incorrect data throughout the text; however, I am not too sure how to manipulate the first group without messing up the entire pattern. The first group is just meant to extract the date.

For example, this is what I would like it to do:

```
May 19, 2014 4:13:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext

Group 1: May 19, 2014 4:13:04 PM
Group 2: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
Group 3: log
Group 4: INFO
...so on
```

Comment: @hwnd This works great, but it fails when org. isn't used. In some cases in my log  file, I have com. instead. Anyway to accommodate both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for this regex:

```
^([A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{1,2}, \d{4} [^co]+) (\S+) (\w+)([^:]+): ([\s\S]+?)$
```

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sL4eR0/9)

Answer (score 0):

Below regex would capture all the strings separately except the date and `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext`,

```
^([^co]*) ([^\s]*) (\w+)\n([^\:]*)(?:\:) (\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sL4eR0/6)